# Biggest value from two or more fields

Tags: mysql

I need to get the biggest value from two fields:

```
SELECT MAX(field1), MAX(field2)
```

Now, how can I get biggest value from these two?

Comment: `GREATEST()` for the biggest similarly `LEAST()` for the smallest.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You may want to use the [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function:

```
SELECT GREATEST(field1, field2);
```

If you want to get the absolute maximum from all the rows, then you may want to use the following:

```
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(field1), MAX(field2));
```

Example 1:

```
SELECT GREATEST(1, 2);
+----------------+
| GREATEST(1, 2) |
+----------------+
|              2 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Example 2:

```
CREATE TABLE a (a int, b int);

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (3, 1);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 4);

SELECT GREATEST(MAX(a), MAX(b)) FROM a;
+--------------------------+
| GREATEST(MAX(a), MAX(b)) |
+--------------------------+
|                        4 |
+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Comment: don't know why, but only `GREATEST(MAX(field1), MAX(field2))` is working. Else wrong number is returned (not biggest)

Comment: @Qiao: Yes, you would need `SELECT GREATEST(MAX(field1), MAX(field2));` to get the absolute maximum from all the rows. If you use `SELECT GREATEST(field1, field2);` you will get back a result-set with the maximum between field1 and field2 for each row.

Comment: That's what I was looking for I was sure there is a function for this, but i had no clue of the name, now it makes perfect sense :)

Comment: As each `MAX()` has to maintain a running maximum value as rows are processed, it might be slightly more efficient to use `MAX(GREATEST(field1,field2))`.

Answer (score 49):

In case you're selecting the GREATEST() for each row

```
SELECT GREATEST(field1, field2)
```

It will return **NULL** if one of the fields is NULL. You could use IFNULL to solve this

```
SELECT GREATEST(IFNULL(field1, 0), IFNULL(field2, 0))
```

Comment: Yeah, sad you have to do all those `IFNULL`s even when you have two dozen fields to compare!

Answer (score 6):

```
mysql> SELECT GREATEST(2,0);
        -> 2
```

So, try:

```
mysql> SELECT GREATEST(MAX(field1), MAX(field2));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use of GREATEST/LEAST with MIN/MAX

**GREATEST/LEAST**: used with the columns, when you want to find the max or min value from the various columns.

**MIN/MAX**: used with the rows, when you want to find the max or min value from the various rows:

**Example table:**

[image]

```
SELECT GREATEST(col_a, col_b, col_c) FROM temp;
```

[image]

```
SELECT MIN(GREATEST(col_a, col_b, col_c)) FROM temp; # 3 as output
SELECT MAX(GREATEST(col_a, col_b, col_c)) FROM temp; # 9 as output


SELECT LEAST(col_a, col_b, col_c) FROM temp;
```

[image]

```
SELECT MIN(LEAST(col_a, col_b, col_c)) FROM temp; # 1 as output
SELECT MAX(LEAST(col_a, col_b, col_c)) FROM temp; # 7 as output
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT max( CASE
                WHEN field1 > field2 THEN field1
                ELSE field2
            END ) as biggestvalue 
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: This solution is not feasible when I have 100s of columns.

Comment: @Deepak, ok, but an answer from over 10 years ago when I did not know of the "GREATEST" or "LEAST" function call, but the original post asked about 2 columns, and if you have a table with 100s of columns in it of similar context, then you have a serious database design problem to reconsider.

Comment: Yes right, thanks for the clarification. Now your comment will help others on what to use when.