# How to select the highest score of more than one same courses in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, max

**TABLE: MAST_CAT_HS**

EMPLID  |  CONV_GRADE_OFF | MAST_CAT

---

1      90              CHEM

1      90              PHSC

1      75              MATH

1      95              MATH

1      50              ENGL

1      90              MATH

1      90              CHEM

1      90              PHSC

1      65              BUS

2      90              ENGL

2      80              MATH

**Want to get result like this:**

EMPLID  |  CONV_GRADE_OFF | MAST_CAT

---

1          90              CHEM

1          90              PHSC

1          95              MATH

1          50              ENGL

1          65              BUS

2          90              ENGL

2          80              MATH

**Unfortunately,we cannot make any assumption on MAST_CAT column =(
Here is my query.It does not merge the multiple rows with same course and same scores into
single row.
My approach is this:**

```
SELECT sr1.EMPLID, sr1.CONV_GRADE_OFF, sr1.MAST_CAT
FROM MAST_CAT_HS sr1
LEFT JOIN MAST_CAT_HS sr2
  ON sr1.EMPLID = sr2.EMPLID 
 AND sr1.MAST_CAT = sr2.MAST_CAT
 AND sr1.CONV_GRADE_OFF < sr2.CONV_GRADE_OFF
WHERE sr2.EMPLID IS NULL
```

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615697/mysql-biggest-value-from-two-fields ---This maybe?

Comment: Your query would return the specified resultset if you added the `DISTINCT` keyword after `SELECT`, or if you added `GROUP BY sr1.EMPLID, sr1.CONV_GRADE_OFF, sr1.MAST_CAT` following the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT emplid, MAX(conv_grade_off), MAST_CAT
FROM MAST_CAT_HS
GROUP by elplid, mast_cat
```

That groups by the ip and mast_cat and selects the maximum score of the grouped rows

Comment: It works! very simple and straightforward =) Thank you so much!@user1281385