# MYSQL - Compare between 5 dates and order by most recent

Tags: mysql

I'm really blocked at an advanced query, if someone can help me

I have a table mysql that looks like:

customers(id, appointment_date1, appointment_date2, appointment_date3, appointment_date4)

I'm looking for a query that list me what is the next most recent appointment

Before I do this query :

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN (customers.appointment_date1 != '0000-00-00' AND DATE(customers.appointment_date1) >= CURDATE()) THEN customers.appointment_date1
    WHEN (customers.appointment_date2 != '0000-00-00' AND DATE(customers.appointment_date2) >= CURDATE()) THEN customers.appointment_date2
    WHEN (customers.appointment_date3 != '0000-00-00' AND DATE(customers.appointment_date3) >= CURDATE()) THEN customers.appointment_date3
    WHEN (customers.appointment_date4 != '0000-00-00' AND DATE(customers.appointment_date4) >= CURDATE()) THEN customers.appointment_date4
END as appointment
ORDER BY appointment ASC
```

But it's wrong, it doesn't work correctly.

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need THE next most recent appointment or the list of the next most recent appointments ?

Comment: You're having to work harder by not normalizing this structure.  Try using a new table `appointments` rather than using a bunch of columns in the customers table.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work correctly'? Could you provide sample data, expected result and current result?

Comment: This will help with sorting by date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511882/sorting-by-date-time-in-descending-order but you may want to put the data into a temporary table first, so you can get the data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859391/create-a-temporary-table-in-a-select-statement-without-a-separate-create-table

Answer (score 1):

I'd use nested mysql `if()` functions in `select` clause, like :

```
select *
from(
    select if(date1<date2&&date1>curdate(),date1,
            if(date2<date3&&date2>curdate(),date2,
             if(date3>curdate(),date3, 'nothing')
            )
           ) as date
    from dates
) as dates
order by dates.date desc;
```

EDIT : as per Zika's comment

```
SELECT IF(LEAST(
           IFNULL(date1,'0000-00-00'),
           IFNULL(date2,'0000-00-00'),
           IFNULL(date3,'0000-00-00')
           )!='0000-00-00',
          LEAST(
           IFNULL(date1,'0000-00-00'),
           IFNULL(date2,'0000-00-00'),
           IFNULL(date3,'0000-00-00')
          ),
          'aucune date'
         )
FROM dates;
```

Comment: And why is that? I think that CASE is more readable in this example

Comment: using `CASE` here assumes that appointment_date1<appointment_date2<appointment_date3, etc... but we don't know it. (as per https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html, "each WHEN clause search_condition expression is evaluated until one is true")

Comment: I guess you can use `LEAST()` function (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615697/mysql-biggest-value-from-two-or-more-fields) actually :)