# How to select a higher value from 3 three different fields using a case statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 fields (field_1, field_2, field_3) all the have the same potential value (high, medium, low). I want to write a case statement that  would select the higher value of the 3 fields and put it in field_4. The higher value being in the obvious order high, medium, low. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - biggest value from two or more fields](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2615697/mysql-biggest-value-from-two-or-more-fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you want with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3,
    CASE WHEN field_1 = 'high' OR field_2 = 'high' OR field_3 = 'high' THEN 'high'
         WHEN field_1 = 'medium' OR field_2 = 'medium' OR field_3 = 'medium' THEN 'medium'
         WHEN field_1 = 'low' OR field_2 = 'low' OR field_3 = 'low' THEN 'low'
    END AS field_4
FROM yourTable
```

This assumes that there are no `NULL` values in any of the original three `field` columns and that the only values present are `low`, `medium`, and `high`.